# Is there any way to view an overall Win/Loss record for online multiplayer in MK8?

Tags: mario-kart-8

In MKWii and MK7, it was possible to view a win/loss record for your online racing, with a "win" awarded for each person you finished ahead of, and a "loss" for each person you finished behind in a race. E.g. finishing 3rd in a 8 player race would give you 5 wins and 2 losses. In MK7 you could view an overall record, and you could also see your record against individual players or "rivals" from the "Friends and rivals" screen. The feature for showing your records against individuals is again something included in MK8 - however, there is no (apparent) option to view and overall win/loss record (i.e. total wins/losses against all players).

Has this option been removed from MK8 or is there a way that you can see this data?

Answer (score 1):

**Nope**, there is not such an option. It is a shame that it was deleted, because it was indeed a good way to check your skills. It's only viewable for rivals, as you said in the question.

**Update**: on 27 of august Nintendo will release an update for Mario Kart which will include this option:

- Drivers will now have the option to display the course map on the TV screen during races
- **Users will be able to check out statistics such as their total number of coins accumulated, win-loss record from online play, and their most frequently selected character overall**
- Users will be able to change options of others’ Mario Kart TV downloaded highlight reels, such as changing the focus to a new character or event
- The order of the menu after each race will be changed to “Next Race”, followed by “Watch Highlight Reel”
- The game will remember the most recent customised kart settings that were selected, even if the Wii U system is powered down
- Improvements to stability of connection in online play to enhance the user experience

Source: [Nintendo](http://www.nintendo.co.uk/News/2014/August/Nintendo-adds-three-Mercedes-Benz-cars-and-enhancements-to-Mario-Kart-8-from-27th-August-909198.html) itself

Comment: disappointing isn't it.

Comment: Yes, it quite is. I'm not sure why they left it out? It doesn't have any negative consequences I think.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister there will be an update end of this month which will make it possible. Hooray!